# Shell script variable value

Tags: bash, shell, variables, if-statement

I have value 0.000000 written in a file. I open the file and assign it to a variable.
But when i compare it's value like `if [ "$var" -eq "0.000000" ]` it doesn't evaluate to true.
What could be the reason?

Moreover, if the file has just 0, and if i compare it's value `[ "$var" -eq "0" ]` it evaluates as expected to true.

Comment: Are you sure that the 0.00000 isn't being interpreted as a number and thus just equal to zero?

Comment: bash does not support floating point. -eq operates on integers, use str comparison instead. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: i check it with 0 only as well, but its also returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Fredrik (+1 for him) said, bash does not support floating point. If you must, use string comparison:

```
if [ "$var" = "0.000000" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might switch to ksh which supports floating point arithmetic:

```
$ bash
a=0.00000
[ $a -eq 0 ] && echo ok || echo ko
bash: [: 0.00000: integer expression expected
ko
$ ksh
$ a=0.00000
$ [ $a -eq 0 ] && echo ok || echo ko
ok
$ a=0.00001
$ [ $a -eq 0 ] && echo ok || echo ko
ko
```

Comment: Sure, but Perl and Python are using totally different syntaxes while switching from bash to ksh (and reciprocally) is less disruptive.

Answer (score 1):

bash can't understand floats. Try using `bc`, which will return 1 if the equality is true, 0 otherwise.

```
if [ $(bc <<< $var==0.000000) -eq 1 ]
then

fi
```

or `expr`:

```
if [ $(expr $var == 0.000000) -eq 1 ]
then

fi
```